# How do you stage new files on Git using Notepad++ with a Mac?

Tags: git, macos, notepad++, addition

I tried to stage the files the same way that I created the first snapshot.

```
git add orange.html blue.html
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'orange.html' did not match any files
```

Comment: whats the output of git status

Comment: maybe you aren't in the correct directory

Comment: "On branch master     nothing to commit, working directory clean"